# Unresolved reference: inflate

Tags: android, view, layout-inflater

```
override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
            var myView=LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_custom_listitem, null)
            var myNote=listNotes[p0]
            myView.tvTitle.text=myNote.noteName
            myView.tvDes.text=myNote.noteDes
```

The output is:

> Unresolved reference: inflate

I selected import under the red mark at inflate, but there is no change. The packages have been imported but inflate is still underlined in red. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

```
override fun getView(p0: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View {
            var myView= getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_custom_listitem, null)
            var myNote=listNotes[p0]
            myView.tvTitle.text=myNote.noteName
            myView.tvDes.text=myNote.noteDes
        }
```

I modified my code as above, but I am not sure if this is right or will do the same job.

Comment: Mention detail properly. It's a adapter class. You haven't mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this .

You have not return the view and must initialize the TextView

```
  @Override
    fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {
        val myView: View = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_custom_listitem, null)
        val tvTitle= myView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvTitle) as TextView
        val tvDes= myView.findViewById<View>(R.id.tvDes) as TextView
        tvTitle.text = "some value"
        tvDes.text = "another value"
        return myView
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's an adapter class Override method...

```
val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.row_custom_listitem,null)
```